# Maven reuse properties from Super POM

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, parent-pom

I want to use the properties defined in the Super POM:

```
<properties>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>
```

In the POM.xml file of my project:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 22, column 16
```

Then I have to add the same properties to the POM.xml of my project to make it work. Is there another way to do this, it seems really inefficient to do this. By the way I am new to maven.

Super POM:

```
 <!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated on 2015-09-04T05:07:36                                       -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'com.mycompany.webapp:web-app:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT'                        -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>web-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <directory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target</directory>
    <finalName>web-app</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/marcelo/Documents/MavenTest/web-app/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>web-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <!-- Spring Core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          <version>${logback.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jstl -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>${jstl.version}</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>web-app</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: effective pom is something what maven actually used for building project. it is combination of parent pom, application pom and settings. so are you sure is it what do you mean by effective pom? and what is structure of your project?

Comment: Yes, it is that POM that I am referring to. The structure is the standard structure created by IntelliJ for a maven web app.

Comment: As this should work, please post the POM and the effective POM.

Comment: I added both files, as you can see I have to put the same properties that are in the effective POM in the POM.xml file of my project.

Comment: your pom seems fine, i tried it in my eclipse, and it builds without any problem. by addition line `line 22` listed in error in your pom has nothing to do with spring, are you sure you are building right project?

Comment: Yes, this works fine, the problem is that, as you can see, both POM files have the same properties, it would be more useful to define them only one time on the parent "effective" POM and not again in the POM file of my project, that is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use properties from a parent pom your child project must extend from parent. But in order to extend, your parent pom packaging must be `pom` instead of `war`. IMHO, it would be best if you create a real parent pom and put all the properties there and than extend other two web app from that project.

Here is an example;

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>parent-pom</name>

    <properties>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>web-app-1</module>
        <module>web-app-2</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Than on your different projects (for example I will use `web-app-1` and `web-app-2`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-app-1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-app-2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

And your project structure will be

```
project-root
-- pom.xml (this is parent pom)
-- web-app-1
---- pom.xml
-- web-app-2
---- pom.xml
```

If you have a local maven repository ([nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go/), [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti) etc) you can even release parent pom and sub module differently.

And if you want to override a property simply redefine it in your sub projects (web-app-1 and web-app-2)

Comment: This looks like a good option, but is it good practice to have a parent POM file in the root of the project so the other projects could inherit it? Because it looks kind of out of place to have a POM file there.

Comment: @Frak I think it is a good practice to have a parent pom. For example, lets look into [apache camel's source](https://github.com/apache/camel) code. In project-root it has a parent-pom and all the sub modules inherits it. Also, parent-pom inherits apache's default parent pom from maven repository. Apache camel is using the both perspectives I mentioned above.

Comment: Excellent example, thanks for the information and the link !

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling effective POM sounds like a parent POM.

Your POM needs this

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```